# How to properly filter emails through EXIM system filter?

Tags: email, email-server, exim, webmail, cpanel

My server recently encountered a large volume of incoming spam messages. For each message, Exim agent generated a message with the following content for the sender:

**"Mail Delivery Failed: Returning Message to Sender ..."**

So I encountered a large volume of queued emails sent from the system to my domain.

I set Webmail to **forward all unrouted email for my domain to ":blackhole:"** (from: "cPanel > Default Address > Default Address Maintenance > Discard (Not Recommended)")

But what happened is that the agent now sends (queues) the same messages from my domain directly to the first senders.

I also tried to prevent sending emails containing a specific subject or body by editing WHM EXIM system filter:

`if $header_subject: contains "Example spam subject" or $message_body conains "Example spam body" or $message_body conains "..." then seen finish endif`

But no result.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably stop bouncing after accepting; this leads to backscatter spam.